# What are Imported class files and from where do they get imported from?

Tags: java, class, import

What is the meaning import classes and from where are they imported from?

Example

```
package game;

import game.sprites.PlayerSprite;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Vector;
import litecom.Trace;
import litecom.gfxe.LoaderTarget2;
import litecom.gfxe.Timer;
import litecom.scoreclient2.ScoreClient2;
```

Now I know from where the LoaderTarget2.class ScoreClient2.class and Timer.class is imported from. They are imported from the class it self "Game" the path would be /litecom/gfxe/Timer.class. But where do the Vector.class come? or the URL.class or Applet.class?

Comment: From the Java runtime environment; they are classes provided by Java itself.

Comment: From the `classpath`. The JDK (where `java.lang.*` etc comes from) is implied in the classpath of the JVM.

Comment: classpath? dude if i type /java/util/Vector.class it doesnt work

Comment: the only 2 folders in this "Game.class" is litcom and game then theres sprite folder within the game folder

Comment: We cannot teach you the entire foundation of Java by answering one question here. Go read.

Comment: ok, so if the url.class is coming from there i would be able to see the url wich the game.class file uses in url.class?

Comment: "dude", if you unzip your JDK file (eg java-install/jre/lib/rt.jar) `/java/util/Vector.class` is *exactly* what you'll find

Comment: Is it your first day at `Java`? You must go through the initial learning program before start of programming in `Java`, what makes me feel strange is your program is so _advance_ that it needs `import` of classes like `URL`, `awt.*`, etc and you are asking from where they came, it makes me to think that you've downloaded your code rather then learn'n'code.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Vector.class , URL.class and Applet.class are imported from java class library which are found in "rt.jar" .

Answer (score 0):

Imported classes come from JAR files (generally) that are in your classpath.  `import` a way to tell the compiler that your code needs external code, and which code.

Consider:

```
Bug b = new Bug();
```

is valid, but where does Bug() get defined?  The compiler will look through your imports until it finds a class in the classpath that defines Bug.

Also, bear in mind that there's no relationship to the file paths in the classpath and the locations/packages of the java classes.  In the Bug example, say the `Bug` class is in bug.jar, and `Bug`'s package is `this.that.Bug`.  bug.jar can be *anywhere* on the file system, permissions permitting.  The classpath just has to include its location.  In java, we refer to the class's packages, not their physical locations.  So regardless of where bug.jar lives on the file system, I can always import `this.that.Bug` or refer to the class explicitly if necessary:

```
  this.that.Bug b = new this.that.Bug();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you launch the JRE, by default there is a bootstrap class loader. The bootstrap class loader contains all of the classes defined by the language. They generally live in a file names 'classes.jar' or 'rt.jar' in your Java installation, but there's no guarantee. These classes are importable like any other classes.